# how to build a library file (jar file) from my java classes?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have created some supportive java classes for help and speed-up the development. Now I want to build a jar file ( hibernate jar files like that) collecting these java classes. then I can add that jar file to other project and use it.. how can I possible to do that.? or any other suggestions?

Comment: Your IDE does not support this ?

Comment: There are various ways you can achieve that either on the console or with the help of some additional tools like Ant or Maven. Could you be more specific in what direction you want to go and what the scope of your project is (how many classed, resources dependencies)?

Comment: its just a small project using struts , hib  and some amount of spring.. ;) . I'm using STS IDE.

Comment: Hi have you solved your issue ? Give some feedback to the answers.. Either worked or not ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a jar file by using the following commands

```
jar -cvf
```

here c indicates create, v for verbose & f stands for files to be included inside your jar.
If your class files includes main class you need to include manifest file to mention the main class name.

Note: If you want an standalone executable jar which includes another jar files then you there might be a problem while executing the standalone jar because the added libraries will not be placed in classpath at the time of execution. You can take help of eclipse IDE which will create a jar file which includes the jar file executes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build a JAR it depends on your IDE.
In Netbeans for example you can run the clean and build command whereafter your JAR will be placed in PROJECT_FOLDER>Dist

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then try installing fatjar plugin. Once installed then right click on your java project and you can build it as jar. If you need you can include the dependencies too in the result jar.

Comment: I'm using STS ide.. based on Eclipse so, that plugin also support to the STS?

Answer (score 0):

First Convert your .java file to .class with the command line.

```
javac ClassName.java
```

Next, create a JAR file containing the ClassName.class file. Type the following in your command window:

```
jar cvf ClassName.jar ClassName.class
```

This creates a JAR file, ClassName.jar, and places the ClassName.class file inside it.
For further reference [See the Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use maven to bundle your jar, deploy it to a private repo like [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), then pull down the jar in the second project with maven dependency management. Technically you don't need nexus, you could just build the jar and have it go to your local .m2 repo. Then when the second project gets build it will pull the jar from your local .m2 repo. You can achieve this by running mvn install on the jar project.

Easiest steps

Setup your first project, the jar project, to be built with maven. You will need to setup a pom.xml in the project root. You should also follow a [standard folder layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). You don't need to use this layout for maven but it makes things easier. Maven will allow you to override all of these locations in the build element of the pom.xml.

Next search google for how to setup a basic pom.xml. Set your first project to package type jar. Here's an example pom.xml of what it may look like for your jar project. Don't paste the ... they are just there as placeholders because I don't know the details of how you want to build your project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.your.package.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-jar-project-name</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>your-jar-project-name</name>
    <version>1.00</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
     ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
     ...
    </build>



</project>
```

After you have the pom.xml in the root, cd to that directory and run mvn install. This will build the jar and place it in your local .m2 repo. Next you will need to setup a pom.xml in the project that needs the jar project. Insert this in the dependencies section of the project that needs to use the jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.your.package.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-jar-project-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.00</version>
</dependency>
```

Good luck and have fun!